# Magnolia Validation field

Tags: java, validation, input, field, magnolia

When editing an Input Field and trying to add a Validator I get this error:

[The validator field I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVk5n.png)

Cannot convert class java.util.LinkedHashSet to class java.lang.String

I understand the error but not sure how to fix it.

Did anyone run into this problem and how did you fix it?

My magnolia version: 5.4.6

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I guess the context correctly, this *validation* field is from the [Form module](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Form+module); more precisely it is a [Twin-column field](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Twin-column+field), configured in the `formEdit` dialog.

The "Cannot convert class" error usually occurs when the Vaadin field is incompatible with the Magnolia/JCR property it's trying to save to.

Use the [JCR Browser app](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/JCR+Browser+app) to see (and delete) if there is any pre-saved String value for the `validation` property of this component. Well-formed "multi-values" are displayed within square brackets, *e.g.* `[email]`.

I could not reproduce this error on the [Magnolia Demo](https://demo.magnolia-cms.com)—currently running 5.6.3, so if the above doesn't solve it, this could come from the dialog/field configuration, if you use a custom one. As a reference, the `formEdit` dialog is configured at:
`/modules/form/dialogs/formEdit/form/tabs/tabMain/fields/validation`.